# Conditional Expected Value of Product of Normal and Log-Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, distributions

Could someone please provide the answer and steps to solve this expression?

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)\right|\left.\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)>0\right]\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
$E$ is the expectation operator.
\begin{eqnarray*}
X\sim N\left(\mu_{X},\sigma_{X}^{2}\right);Y\sim N\left(\mu_{Y},\sigma_{Y}^{2}\right);X\;\text{and }Y\text{ are independent. Also, }k<0
\end{eqnarray*}

## KEY MISSING LINK

The above expression depends on proving the below general expression or at least showing that it holds for the special case of Normal and Log-Normal distribution.

$E[UV\mid UV>c] = E[UE[V\mid UV>c]]$

Here, $U,V$ are independent random variables that could be discrete or continuos and follow any probability distribution. $E$ is the expectation operator. $c$ is a constant.

Of course, for our main question we require only the case where one of them is normally distributed and the other is log-normal? Say,  $U$ is log-normal and $V$ is normal. Is the above identity true for this special case?

This is posed as a separate question due to its importance: [Proof of Simplification of Conditional Expectation of Product of Random Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162657/proof-of-simplification-of-conditional-expectation-of-product-of-random-variable)

## STEPS TRIED

## 0) JOINT CONDITIONAL DENSITY

I am having difficulty coming up with the conditional joint density to use in the above expectation. The joint density function of just $X$ and $Y$ is straight forward and follows from the standard density function for the bivariate normal case. How would we incorporate the conditional aspect into the joint density function?

## 1) NORMAL LOG-NORMAL MIXTURE PAPER BY YANG

(Link: http://repec.org/esAUSM04/up.21034.1077779387.pdf)

This paper has the first four central moments without proof (Equation 5 in above paper). If someone could provide these proofs, that might shed more light on the problem above.

The variables in the Yang paper are correlated, which is easy to apply to above; but they also have zero mean in the paper, which in our case does not apply directly, since we have non zero mean.

## 2)OTHER RELATED LINKS

a) Interesting question about an expectation involving a slightly modified form of the normal log-normal mixture. Though this lacks the conditional aspect, and hence needs some modification before it can be used for the problem above.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142841/covariance-in-normal-lognormal-nln-mixture

b) Another question on the normal log-normal mixture though this lacks a deeper discussion.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159818/combination-of-a-normal-r-v-with-a-log-normal-one

c) Question on conditional expectation of product of independent random variables. It would be good to know which aspects from this are applicable in our case.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544410/result-and-proof-on-the-conditional-expectation-of-the-product-of-two-random-var

d) Other interesting questions on conditional expectation of independent random variables.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380866/conditional-expectations-for-independent-random-variables?rq=1

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55524/rule-with-independent-random-variables-and-conditional-expectations?rq=1

## 3) TAYLOR SERIES APPROXIMATIONS

Would it be possible to use taylor serious approximations here? I am little confused due to the conditional expectation and the normal log normal mixture? Any pointers on whether this is possible and how to proceed further or whether this is not applicable here would be great.

## 4) USING STANDARD NORMAL (SEEMS LIKE A DEAD END)

I know that if we can express this sum using the standard normal as below, there is a solution. Please advice on how to do this or other alternatives to solve the above would be helpful as well. This seems to be a dead end as confirmed by experts on this forum. But still keeping here if someone discovers a way to continue using this approach.

\begin{eqnarray*}
W=\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)<=>\mu+\sigma Z\text{ where, }Z\sim N\left(0,1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[W\sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)\Rightarrow W=\mu+\sigma Z\;;\; W>0\Rightarrow Z>-\mu/\sigma\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
We then need to determine, $\mu\text{ and }\sigma$.

We have for every standard normal distribution, $Z$, and for every
$u,$ $Pr\left[Z>\text-u\right]=Pr\left[Z<u\right]=\mathbf{\Phi}\left(u\right)$.
Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and
CDF, respectively. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.Z\right|Z>-u\right] & = & \frac{1}{\mathbf{\Phi}\left(u\right)}\left[\int_{-u}^{\infty}t\phi\left(t\right)dt\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\mathbf{\Phi}\left(u\right)}\left[\left.-\phi\left(t\right)\right|_{-u}^{\infty}\right]=\frac{\phi\left(u\right)}{\mathbf{\Phi}\left(u\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence we have, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.Y\right|Y>0\right] & = & \mu+\sigma E\left[\left.Z\right|Z>\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \mu+\frac{\sigma\phi\left(\mu/\sigma\right)}{\mathbf{\Phi}\left(\mu/\sigma\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Setting, $\psi\left(u\right)=u+\phi\left(u\right)/\Phi\left(u\right)$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.Y\right|Y>0\right]=\sigma\psi\left(\mu/\sigma\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @gung, Please note above the steps I tried. Expressing the above as a standard normal variable with appropriate mean and variance has a solution. So the trick would be to convert the above to a suitable standard normal. If there are alternatives, please also suggest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just also found the Paper on Normal and Log Normal mixture by Yang, but it treats correlated variables and am not yet sure how to get the conditional expectation. Please advice on closed form solutions that might exist for the above.

Comment: What is the subscript $T$ in your first formula?

Comment: Sorry, I should either have removed that or clarified earlier it is time .. I am taking the expectation at time T ..  Please let me know if you need any further details ...  Any suggestions on answers and steps would be appreciated?

Comment: Unless $X$ has a tiny variance, $W$ won't be anywhere near normally distributed: that approach is a dead end.

Comment: @whuber Would taylor series approximations be possible in this case? I am little thrown off due to the conditional expectation and the normal log normal mixture.. Please advice ..

Comment: I would not expect Taylor series to be an effective approach where lognormal distributions and products are involved, unless there are severe restrictions on the coefficients and the variances of the distributions involved.

Comment: Could you please point me to some source on where the taylor approximation would be useful and why it would fail for the lognormal?

Comment: Any reference that analyzes the error would do it.  First, though, I recommend that you simplify the question by eliminating redundant parameters. It can be reduced to one about $e^XY$ where $X$ has a mean-zero Normal distribution and $Y$ has an arbitrary Normal distribution. That simplification will clarify the nature of the problem and perhaps help you determine whether a Taylor series approximation would be appropriate.

Comment: @whuber I am looking at the joint distribution of X and Y, which we know can be easily arrived at since both are normal. We can even take the expected value of the product, but it is the conditional expected value that is causing issues for the joint distribution. Do you know any source that looks at conditional distributions of joint distributions with a constant added.

Comment: All, I am still trying to understand if this problem is worth pursuing further or just settle for a numerical solution. The joint probability distribution seems to be another approach but again the conditional distribution and the constant added in, seems to cause issues. Any suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What is the intended use of the result?  That bears on what form of answer is needed, to include whether a stochastic (Monte Carlo) simulation approach might be adequate,  And even the bigger picture matter of is this problem necessary to solve, and did someone come up with this problem as a way of solving a higher level problem, and there might be a better approach to the higher level problem which doesn't require this.

Here is a stochastic (Monte Carlo) simulation solution in MATLAB.

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; k = -1; % Made up values for illustrative purpose
n = 1e8; % Number of replications
mux = 10; sigmax = 4; sigmay = 7; % Made up values for illustrative purposes
X = mux + sigmax * randn(n,1); Y = sigmay * randn(n,1); Y1 = a + b + c + d * Y;
success_index = exp(X).*Y1 > 0; % replications in which condition is true
num_success = sum(success_index);
Cond_Sample = exp(X(success_index)) .* Y1(success_index) + k;
disp([num_success mean(Cond_Sample) std(Cond_Sample)/sqrt(num_success)])
1.0e+09 *
0.058475265000000   1.502775087443930   0.057342191058931
```

Comment: Meant to add, I feel that this is a such a fundamental combination of normal and log normal, so there must be some solution if not approximation available. If there is not, given the rather simple nature of the problem, any further progress or breakthroughs would be helpful to many it seems. I would be happy to put a bounty on this as soon as I can, which is after I get five more points.

Comment: At this point, i think I've given enough freebies for the benefit of some billionaire hedge fund tycoon.  They can pony up if they want more specialized help and advice.  Or is this an academic project?

Comment: This is an academic project. I am not billionaire hedge fund tycoon :-) If this were not academic, then a simulation would have killed it long back. Finding a better answer would be mainly in the interest of gaining knowledge and spreading it … Right?

Comment: Perhaps we should collaborate. You can send an invite to my LinkedIn account linked in my profile.  And I wasn't thinking you were the billionaire hedge fund tycoon - more likely that you were an employee working for the benefit of the billionaire hedge fund tycoon :).

Comment: Since I still don't really know the big picture, i can't assess what kind of solution, if any, is really needed to this. And so why is any of this Normal or Lognormal, and not some fatter tailed distributions?  The simulation approach will still hold up if distributions change, dependencies are introduced, etc.

Comment: You make a good point Mark … A simulation would handle all those cases and as I said earlier, would have been easily solved. But now it is mainly about finding a proper proof or solution to the above, which I think is a very interesting problem. Given how common normal and log normal distributions are, the above should be something we should look to solve.

Comment: I don't think I can reply in chat.  Apparently I only have 1 of the needed 20 stack exchange points to participate in chat. Unless there is a way of migrating Cross Validated points there. See my comment 2 comments back to contact me.

Comment: Contact me per info at https://www.or-exchange.org/users/1263/mark-l-stone .

Comment: You shouldn't have any reputation-based problems participating in chat, Mark.  What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: @whuber, I just put a bounty on this question. Somehow I seem to think that the answer lies in finding a conditional distribution to use in the expectation and solving thereafter … Any suggestions / thoughts, please let me know.

Comment: I believe there is no closed form for the expectation in terms of the conventional transcendental functions. It can be reduced to an integral of a Gaussian times an Error function, but cannot be further simplified in general. These integrals require numerical evaluation.

Comment: whuber, I have had a reply box available in chat ever since I got up to 20 points on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .  Before that,I could see the chat session but could not post.  It specifically said something about needing 20 points on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @whuber, Could you please provide some details and steps to get to the integral involving the Gaussian and error function? Setting up the conditional joint density for the above would be a useful thing to know, I suppose.

Comment: @Mark Obviously you have far more than 20 points! Have you attempted recently to enter any chat session, such as at [Ten Fold](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)?

Comment: As I wrote above, I now have reply box available in chat, and have since I got up to 20 points on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/  a few days ago. When I registered on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ , I was already in the many hundreds on Cross Validated, but only started off with 1 point, even thought at some level it knew who I was. This is unlike when I registered on Cross Validated and at some point had 100 point association bonus between CV and   http://math.stackexchange.com/ and http://mathoverflow.net/ .Not allowed to reply in chat on Cross Validated even when I had > 1000 points.

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

1. The joint density is given by multiplying the densities since they are idp. One variable is just a paramater to the other.
2. $Ye^X$ is not normally distributed so approach (4) wont work.
3. The expressions below might allow you to find some approximation. If not they are relatively easy to evaluate with a computer.

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, denote $c = -k/y$, and $d(y)=\log(-k/y)$. 
Let $Z=e^X$, then
$$E[YZ\mid B] = E[YE[Z\mid B]],$$
and,
$$E[Z\mid Z>c] = e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}\frac{P(X>d-\sigma^2)}{P(X>d)},$$
if $c>0$ and $E[Z] = e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$ otherwise. Thus, since $c>0$ only if $Y<0$,
$$E[YZ\mid B] = \frac{1}{2}e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}\bigg(E[Y\mathbb{1}(Y>0] + E\Big[Y\frac{P(X>d(Y)-\sigma^2)}{P(X>d(Y))}\mathbb{1}(Y<0)\Big]\bigg).$$

The first part is simply
$$\int_0^\infty y f_Y(y)\,dy,$$
and the second
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 y \frac{P(X>log(-\frac{k}{y})-\sigma^2)}{P(X>log(-\frac{k}{y}))}f_Y(y)\,dy.$$

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Here, $k<0$, but I suppose we just change the sign and everything follows. Also, could you please elaborate on the steps to get the below two results? Does the first one follow simply from independence or does it involve some other special properly?    



#1) $$E[YZ\mid B] = E[YE[Z\mid B]],$$


#2) $$E[Z\mid Z>c] = e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}\frac{P(X>d-\sigma^2)}{P(X>d)},$$

Comment: Could you also please explain how you are setting up the conditional density here? $$E[ZY\mid ZY\in B] = \int\int_B zy f_{ZY\mid B}\,dz\,dy = \int y \Big(\int_{-k/y} z f_Z\,dz\Big) f_Y\,dy$$

Comment: There was a mistake in the two-dimensional integral. If you look at it now it should be clear whence $E[YZ\mid B]$ came from-otherwise let me know! The conditional expectation is a standard result found in e.g. the wikipedia article for lognormal. You find it by integrating e^X f_X with some constraints.

Comment: Much appreciative of your clarifications. I see how we would get this, $$E[YZ\mid B] = E[YE[Z\mid B]],$$    But I found this link, while trying to understand this more and perhaps I am confusing something, but would the answer at this link not apply in the our case. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544410/result-and-proof-on-the-conditional-expectation-of-the-product-of-two-random-var

Comment: We have $E[YE[Z\mid B]\neq E[Y]E[Z\mid B]$

Comment: I have added steps based on your suggestion above. Could you eyeball it please for errors and clarify further the one doubt I still have?

Comment: Please note that in your pointers above, there is still one part that is unclear or not completely proved as elaborated in this new question. Could you please clarify the steps in this question or in the new questions? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162657/proof-of-simplification-of-conditional-expectation-of-product-of-random-variable

Answer (score 0):

This solution is due to the suggestions and corrections from @Hunaphu, @whuber, and others. Could someone please verify if all the steps make sense?

## ANSWER STEPS START

Using some notational shortcuts,

Consider,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)\right|\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)>0\right] & = & E\left[k\left|\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)>0\right.\right]+E\left[\left(e^{X}Y\right)\left|\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)>0\right.\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+E\left[\left.\left(Ye^{X}\right)\right|\left.\left(Ye^{X}+k\right)>0\right]\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int\int ye^{x}f\left(\left.ye^{x}\right|\left\{ ye^{x}+k\right\} >0\right)dxdy
\end{eqnarray*}
Here, $f\left(w\right)$ is the probability density function for $w$,
Here, $f\left(w\right)$ is the probability density function for $w$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int\int ye^{x}\frac{f\left(ye^{x};\left\{ ye^{x}+k\right\} >0\right)}{f\left(\left\{ ye^{x}+k\right\} >0\right)}dxdy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[\text{We note that, }ye^{x}>-k>0\Rightarrow y>0\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int\int ye^{x}\frac{f\left(y\right)f\left(e^{x};\left\{ ye^{x}+k\right\} >0\right)}{f\left(\left\{ ye^{x}+k\right\} >0\right)}dxdy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int y\left[\int\frac{e^{x}f\left(e^{x};\left\{ e^{x}>-\frac{k}{y}\right\} \right)}{f\left(e^{x}>-\frac{k}{y}\right)}dx\right]f\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int y\left[\int e^{x}f\left(e^{x}\left|\left\{ e^{x}>-\frac{k}{y}\right\} \right.\right)dx\right]f\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int_{0}^{\left(y<-k\right)}y\left[\int e^{x}f\left(e^{x}\left|\left\{ e^{x}>1\right\} \right.\right)dx\right]f\left(y\right)dy+\int_{\left(y>-k\right)}^{\infty}y\left[\int e^{x}f\left(e^{x}\left|\left\{ e^{x}<1\right\} \right.\right)dx\right]f\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+\int_{0}^{\left(-k\right)}y\left[E\left(\left.W\right|W>c\right)\right]f\left(y\right)dy+\int_{\left(-k\right)}^{\infty}y\left[E\left(\left.W\right|W<c\right)\right]f\left(y\right)dy\quad;\;\text{here, }W=e^{X}\text{ and }c=1
\end{eqnarray*}
Simplifying the inner expectations,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W>c\right)=\frac{1}{P\left(e^{X}>c\right)}\int_{c}^{\infty}w\frac{1}{w\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{ln\left(w\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right]^{2}}dw
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $t=ln\left(w\right)$, we have, $dw=e^{t}dt$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W>c\right)=\frac{1}{P\left(X>ln\left(c\right)\right)}\int_{ln\left(c\right)}^{\infty}\frac{e^{t}}{\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^{2}}dt
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
t-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^{2}=-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{X}^{2}}\left(t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)\right)^{2}+\mu_{X}+\frac{\sigma_{X}^{2}}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W>c\right)=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}Z>ln\left(c\right)\right)}\int_{ln\left(c\right)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]^{2}}dt\quad;Z\sim N\left(0,1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $s=\left[\frac{t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]$
and $b=\left[\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]$
we have, $ds=\frac{dt}{\sigma_{X}}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W>c\right)=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(Z>\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\int_{b}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^{2}}ds
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(Z<\frac{-ln\left(c\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^{2}}ds-\int_{-\infty}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^{2}}ds\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(Z<\frac{-ln\left(c\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[1-\Phi\left(b\right)\right]\quad;\Phi\text{ is the standard normal CDF}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(c\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\Phi\left(-b\right)\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly for the other case,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W<c\right)=\frac{1}{P\left(e^{X}<c\right)}\int_{0}^{c}w\frac{1}{w\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{ln\left(w\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right]^{2}}dw
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $t=ln\left(w\right)$, we have, $dw=e^{t}dt$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W<c\right)=\frac{1}{P\left(X<ln\left(c\right)\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{ln\left(c\right)}\frac{e^{t}}{\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^{2}}dt
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
t-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^{2}=-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{X}^{2}}\left(t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)\right)^{2}+\mu_{X}+\frac{\sigma_{X}^{2}}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W<c\right)=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}Z<ln\left(c\right)\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{ln\left(c\right)}\frac{1}{\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]^{2}}dt\quad;Z\sim N\left(0,1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $s=\left[\frac{t-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]$
and $b=\left[\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right]$
we have, $ds=\frac{dt}{\sigma_{X}}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(\left.W\right|W<c\right)=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(Z<\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^{2}}ds
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{P\left(Z<\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\Phi\left(b\right)\right]\quad;\Phi\text{ is the standard normal CDF}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{\Phi\left(\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\Phi\left(b\right)\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the results for the inner expectations,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)\right|\left(e^{X}Y+k\right)>0\right]=k+\int_{0}^{\left(-k\right)}y\left[\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(c\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\Phi\left(-b\right)\right]\right]f\left(y\right)dy+\int_{\left(-k\right)}^{\infty}y\left[\frac{e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}}{\Phi\left(\frac{ln\left(c\right)-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\left[\Phi\left(b\right)\right]\right]f\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=k+e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}\left[\int_{0}^{\left(-k\right)}y\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} f\left(y\right)dy+\int_{\left(-k\right)}^{\infty}y\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(-\left[\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right]\right)}{\Phi\left(-\left[\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right]\right)}\right\} f\left(y\right)dy\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
=k+e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}\left[\int_{0}^{\left(-k\right)}y\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} f\left(y\right)dy+\int_{\left(-k\right)}^{\infty}y\left\{ \frac{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} f\left(y\right)dy\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}\left[\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} \int_{-\frac{\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}}^{-\left(\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)}\left(\mu_{Y}+\sigma_{Y}z\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz\right.\\
 &  & +\left.\left\{ \frac{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} \int_{-\left(\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)}^{\infty}\left(\mu_{Y}+\sigma_{Y}z\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz\right]\quad;Z\sim N\left(0,1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & = & k+e^{\left(\mu_{X}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}\left[\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} \left\{ \mu_{Y}\left[\Phi\left(-\left[\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right]\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)\right]-\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)^{2}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)^{2}}\right]\right\} \right.\\
 &  & +\left.\left\{ \frac{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} \left\{ \mu_{Y}\left[1-\Phi\left(-\left[\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right]\right)\right]+\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{k+\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)^{2}}\right]\right\} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yeah, that or just do stochastic simulation.  Who are these people sitting in academic judgment who don't allow simulation-based solutions? There are Professors at the most prestigious universities in the world, journals, and books dealing just with stochastic simulation.  Hint: call it stochastic simulation, not Monte Carlo simulation - it sounds more sophisticated and less "vulgar".

Comment: @MarkL.Stone You are funny and right about the stochastic simulation. As I mentioned, at this stage, trhe question is not to make any professor or hedge fund manager happy. It is knowledge for its own sake ... :-)