# Proof for Simplifying Integral involving Gaussian and Error Function

Tags: probability

How do we simplify this integral?

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} yf\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}

Please note $k<0$ here.
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y\sim N\left(\mu_{Y},\sigma_{Y}^{2}\right); k<0
\end{eqnarray*}

Here, $f\left(y\right)$ is the probability density function for $y$, and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is the standard normal CDF.

## STEPS TRIED

Based on other suggestions, please see related link below. It seems one of the two assertions below are valid. But I am not sure if (and which) of these are correct or how we can prove it? Could someone please clarify and provide steps?

I think the second assertion below holds when $\lim_{y\to0^+}$ though I am not sure and hence would appreciate clarifications as well.

How about other cases? (Can this integral be simplied in some region?)

## 1)

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[\int_{-\infty}^{0}\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} yf\left(y\right)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{0}yf\left(y\right)dy\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

## 2)

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\{ \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\left(\mu_{X}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{-ln\left(-\frac{k}{y}\right)+\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)}\right\} yf\left(y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}yf\left(y\right)dy\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

This comes up during the proof for this question. [Conditional Expected Value of Product of Normal and Log-Normal Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157954/conditional-expected-value-of-product-of-normal-and-log-normal-distribution)

Comment: I think it is impossible. ratio in the braces obviously not equal to 1, except when $\sigma_x^2$ equal to zero.

Comment: NB: `\lim_{y\to0^+}` will give you $\lim_{y\to0^+}$, rather than what you have.

Comment: How about other cases? (Say when the integral goes from zero to infinity)

Comment: @KyleKanos Indeed then is the above Integral valid say when we go from zero to infinity?

Comment: @texmex: I was talking about the LaTeX, sorry.

Comment: You should note when you've simultaneously asked the same question elsewhere:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364032/proof-for-simplifying-integral-involving-gaussian-and-error-function.

Comment: @DeepNorth please note I have modified the question ... keen to hear your thoughts...

Comment: The change introduced in your latest edit changes the question. The correct answer now is that the integral is not defined, because the argument of the logarithm will be negative for $y\lt 0$.

Comment: @whuber … Is there no way to deal with such integrals?

Comment: Yes: go back to whatever derivation produced it and find the mistake!  (In general, such integrals sometimes can be defined as complex contour integrals provided you choose an appropriate branch cut for the logarithm--but given how this one arose, that is unlikely to be a fruitful avenue of investigation.)

Comment: Interesting you say that, I won't rule out that there is no mistake … In fact, I have been actively trying to get feedback and verify myself if there are any mistakes in the original derivation, which comes up in the related question at this link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157954/conditional-expected-value-of-product-of-normal-and-log-normal-distribution  Can such integrals arise only due to mistakes? Can they not come up otherwise?

Comment: @Whuber .. Thanks … Do you see any mistakes in the derivations from the original question till we get to this integral? So this integral actually comes up in the normal lognormal mixture conditional expectation.

Comment: I haven't studied your derivation, but evidently at the point you introduce $c$ you go astray. You need to split the integral into two cases at that point, recognizing that an exponential can never be negative. But first you can simplify the original expression even further: find $E[e^XY\,|\,e^XY\gt -k\gt 0]$. Since $e^X\gt 0$, it is impossible for $Y$ to be negative, so you may assume $Y\gt 0$.

Comment: @whuber Please note I have changed the answer to the original question to reflect the new approach. It seems to provide a decent solution. Do you see any issues with any of the steps. Please let me know.

Comment: I can't review the details.  If I were doing this work, then no matter what answer I came up with I would evaluate it for a few typical (and not so typical) values of $k$ and confirm that evaluation with a quick simulation or numerical evaluation of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equalities never hold.

The following analysis illustrates the benefits of simplifying complicated expressions before attempting to analyze them.

---

Because $\Phi$ is the CDF of a continuous variable supported everywhere, it is *strictly* increasing and nonzero.  One way to write this fact is

$$\Phi(z + \lambda) / \Phi(z) \gt 1$$

for any all $z$ and any $\lambda \gt 0$.  Applying this to

$$z = \frac{-\log(-k/y) + \mu_x}{\sigma_x}$$

(assuming $k \gt 0$ in the first integral, where $y\lt 0$, and $k \lt 0$ in the second integral where $y\gt 0$, for otherwise the logarithm is not defined) and

$$\lambda = \sigma_x \gt 0,$$

and observing that the remaining factor $y f(y)$ has a constant sign in either integral, allows us to replace everything in braces $\{\cdots \}$--which is precisely $\Phi(z+\lambda)/\Phi(z)$--by the *strictly smaller value* $1$, achieving a strict inequality.

Since in (1) $yf(y) \lt 0$ and in (2) $yf(y) \gt 0$, the integrand on the left hand side of (1) is strictly greater than the integrand on the right hand side and the integrand of the lhs of (2) is strictly less than the integrand of its rhs.  Integration over any set of positive measure (which is the case here) will preserve such a strict inequality.

Therefore, **there are no possible values of $k$, $\mu_x$, or $\sigma_x$ that make either (1) or (2) true.**

Comment: Appreciative of your clarifications as always. Any suggestions on how we can simplify the two identities above? Also, the part where the logarithm does not hold, how would we tackle that. Please note, the above problems comes up in a related question.  Also, in the original question, I am not sure if the simplification regarding the conditional density is correct. Could you please eyeball the steps at the answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157954/conditional-expected-value-of-product-of-normal-and-log-normal-distribution