# Proof that Conditional Expectation of Sum is Sum of Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.\left(X+k\right)\right|\left(X+k\right)>0\right] & = & E\left[k\left|\left(X+k\right)>0\right.\right]+E\left[X\left|\left(X+k\right)>0\right.\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

$k$ is a constant and $X$ is a random variable that could be discrete, continuous and having any distribution.

Does the above equality hold and if so, please provide the proof.

## QUESTION ORIGIN

Please note, I have assumed the above equality is correct in the proof to the related question here, but would be keen to know if there a formal proof or any cases where this would not hold.

[Conditional Expected Value of Product of Normal and Log-Normal Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157954/conditional-expected-value-of-product-of-normal-and-log-normal-distribution)

Comment: Is this a self-learning question?  Can you show us where you got stuck in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just linearity of expectation.
\begin{align}
\text{E}(X + k \mid X + k > 0) &= \frac{\text{E}(X + k \, ; \, X + k > 0)}{P(X + k > 0)} \\
&= \frac{\text{E}(X\, ; \, X + k > 0) + k P(X + k > 0)}{P(X + k > 0)} \\
&= \text{E}(X \mid X + k > 0) + k.
\end{align}

Comment: What if the sum involves two random variables , i.e. $E[X+Y | X+Y>0]$? Does the linearity also hold here? Thank you